# how to load css and js files dynamically from controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading

I have created angularjs project in that. I have different page and to save the load time I have added all un necessary css and js files which are not required for landing page were loaded from page 2 using lazy loading. Now my problem is if i route from page 1 to page 3. My css ad js files are not load. Kindly provide some work around solution for this.

app.js

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
                        url : '/',
                        templateUrl : "views/login.html",
                        controller : "loginController"
                    })
                    
.state('page1',
                            {
                                url : '/page1',
                                templateUrl : "/page1.html",
                                controller : "page1controller",
                                resolve : {
                                    lazyloadctrl : function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                                            name : 'page1',
                                            files : ['./js/file1.js',
                                                      './js/lib/file1.js',
                                                        './js/lib/file2.js',
                                                          './js/lib/file3.js',
                                                            './js/lib/file4.js',
                                                      './css/part1.css',
                                                     './css/part2.css',
                                                    ]
                                        
                                        }]);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
    .state('page2',
                            {
                                url : '/page2',
                                templateUrl : "/page2.html",
                                controller : "page2controller",
                                resolve : {
                                    lazyloadctrl : function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                                            name : 'page2',
                                            files : ['./js/file2.js']
                                        
                                        }]);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
```

in my controller:

```
if(result=='page1') {
$state.go("page1");
}
else if(result=='page2') {
$state.go("page3");
}
else if(result=='page3') {
$state.go("page3");
}                                       }
```

Comment: please provide your annoying script , then i will exactly fix them.
In case of your description, i recommend you this code.

Comment: @Sophie kindly provide me work around solution i have bunch code. can you specify which code i need to provide

Comment: i want your app.ts file

Comment: @Sophie i have updated my app.js kindly check it

Comment: @Sophie did u get this one right anything required from my side